# targetframeworks conflict in asp net core project

Tags: c#, blazor, netcoreapp3.1

I am trying to change target frameworks in csproj file from `<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>`
to `<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1;net472</TargetFrameworks>` because I am trying reference to library that used net framework. After changing the program not compiling with message

> "Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in
>   the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

What am I doing wrong?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILRGr.png)

Comment: You should be able to reference your net framework assembly in your Blazor project without the need to alter the TargetFrameworks tag.

Comment: That depends on the target framework version of the assembly.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET Core 3.0 requires .NET Core 3.0 or higher. It will not run on (nor compile for) any version of the .NET Framework.

Likewise, ASP.NET Core 3.1 requires .NET Core 3.1 or higher.

You can find more details and links on [the announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/324).